# Updating UI from Runnable with parameters

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I found multiple options to do that on Stackoverflow, but still haven't found a good way to do it with parameters. In my case, I have a thread that continuously needs to update the UI main thread with logging information (I'm not using Asynctask; I'm implementing TileProvider interface from Google Maps)

This is what I have that runs in my thread and it works:

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
...

public void debugMsg(final String msg)
{
   Runnable myRunnable = (new Runnable()
   {
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
        Log.Add(msg); // static function that update the UI in the main thread
     }
   });
 
  mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
}
```

Problem is that if I understand correctly, every time I call debugMsg, it is going to instantiate a new Runnable object. I don't think that's a very good practice especially because it's going to be heavily done, so I would like to know if there is way to reuse that runnable inside my thread. Or maybe there's a better way of doing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse the `Runnable`, you can easily store it as a member variable.

```
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { ... };
}
```

You might think, in case of having parameter, you can use consumer.

```
private Consumer<String> myConsumer = (str) - > { Log.d("tag", str); };
```

And then in debugMsg

```
mainHandler.post(() -> { myConsumer.accept(msg); });
```

However, your lambda still will be an object of functional interface instantiated every time you run `debugMsg`. But the main logic will not be recreated and `myConsumer` will be reused.

UPD:

You can implement Runnable interface yourself, something like

```
public abstract class ParameterisedRunnable implements Runnable {
    
    public String param = "";

    public void setParam(String str) {
        param = str;
    }
}
```

And then just create the instance of ParameterisedRunnable like the regular Runnable (overriding run method).

```
private ParameterisedRunnable myRunnable = new ParameterisedRunnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("tag", param);
    }
}
```

You will able to use it like that.

```
myRunnable.setParam(msg);
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks a good solution, however my app is compatible with API 16 devices and "accept" requires 24. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Also if there is an alternative to using Runnable, I could also try that. I know I can use Messages but I was hoping to use something more simple.

Comment: implement Runnable with fields, and store parameters there.

Comment: @LEM I updated my answer, it shows the approach that was proposed by Alexei

Comment: @Steyrix thanks a lot. It works fine now. Just a little modification. It should be myRunnable = new ParameterisedRunnable() instead of myRunnable = new Runnable()

Comment: @LEM yes, you are right, I made a typo, I am glad it helped you anyways :)